# How to make a link that changes the source of an iframe and scrolles to an anchor on that page

Tags: javascript, iframe, hyperlink, onclick, anchor

I use this code, and it works, but it only works one time. How come?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goToAnchor(name){
window.location.hash = name;}
</script>


<li onclick="goToAnchor('topp');"><a href="test.html" target="iframetest">Tst</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time your call it, it changes `window.location.hash` and causes the browser to scroll to the ID or anchor you specified.  The second time, `window.location.hash` is already set to `topp` (or whatever you passed to `goToAnchor` the first time) and since the `hash` hasn't changed the browser doesn't change the scroll position.

There are various ways to fix this:

1. Don't use JavaScript. Just use links like this: `<a href='#topp'>Topp</a>`
2. Use the [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollIntoView) function to scroll to the element you're targetting:

   ```
   document.getElementById('topp').scrollIntoView();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need javascript?

```
<li><a href="test.html#topp" target="iframetest">Tst</a><li>
```

Comment: That won't work because the page test.html is opened inside the iframetest and I want the parent page to go to the anchor